# Hosted Service scope when running as Azure Web Job

Tags: azure, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-webjobs, asp.net-core-hosted-services

Working on a `BackgroundService` that is published to Azure as a Web Job, I noticed something strange (works fine on Azure, exception when running locally), so I tried to recreate the situation.

`Program.cs`:

```
using TestBackgroundJob;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddScoped<IDummyService, DummyService>();
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

Worker

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private readonly IDummyService _dummyService;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IDummyService dummyService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _dummyService = dummyService;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
}
```

Of course that when I run this local I get an exception, because I try to inject a scoped service inside `Worker` class, that being a `HostedService`, is singleton:

> Cannot consume scoped service 'TestBackgroundJob.IDummyService' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.)'

However if I publish this as a Web Job on Azure, the code works fine. I could not found any articles that explain this. Looks like when running on Azure, the scope of `Worker` class is changed from singleton to scoped. Is that what really happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Worker always has `Singleton` lifetime and won't change.
But let's see what happens when you want to create a default host (`CreateDefaultBuilder` method):

**Default builder settings**

The CreateDefaultBuilder method:

- Sets the content root to the path returned by GetCurrentDirectory.
- Loads host configuration from:

  - Environment variables prefixed with DOTNET_.
  - Command-line arguments.
- Loads app configuration from:

  - appsettings.json.
  - appsettings.{Environment}.json.
  - User secrets when the app runs in the Development environment.
  - Environment variables.
  - Command-line arguments.
- Adds the following logging providers:

  - Console
  - Debug
  - EventSource
  - EventLog (only when running on Windows)
- Enables **scope validation** and dependency validation when the environment is **Development**.

As you can see the scope validation only happens in the Development (local) mode but when you publish it on Azure it will run in the **Production** mode.

So why it's important to take care about not resolving Scope service to Singleton?

It's all about using resources since when you use the Scope service in the Singleton then it will behave like a singleton and stay alive on the application lifetime!

It is recommended to use `IServiceScopeFactory` for solving your issue.

For reading more about Generic Host in .net, here is the place:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea about the connection between CreateDefaultBuilder and scope validation. 

In the original code (the one where I first noticed this behavior) the service is needed in both ExecuteAsync() and StopAsync() (same instance is needed). So creating a scope with  IServiceScopeFactory doesn't really help in my case. I guess some refactoring is needed in order for us to use "Scoped" lifetime.

Comment: @FlorinGhisa you can handle it by caching the object and dispose it on the stop method.